# In texinfo, how to specify a bash single quote?

Tags: pdf, unicode, texinfo

I am writing a package using the [GNU build system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system). The documentation hence is in the [texinfo](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/) format. As a result, executing `make` converts the texinfo file into the info format, and executing `make pdf` automatically produces a pdf file.

In the texinfo file, I have something like this:

```
@verbatim
awk '{...}' data.txt
@end verbatim
```

However, in the pdf, the "basic" single quotes ([U+0027](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27/index.htm)) in the awk command above are transformed into "curvy" single quotes ([U+2019](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm)) so that, if one does a copy-paste of the command from the pdf into a terminal, bash complains ("syntax error"). This forces the user to edit the command he just copy-pasted. Same problem occurs if I replace [@verbatim](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/texinfo.html#g_t_0040verbatim) by [@example](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/texinfo.html#g_t_0040example). I searched the [texinfo manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/texinfo.html) but couldn't find a way to specify apostrophes. I am using texinfo version 5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karl Berry (via the bug-texinfo [mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-texinfo/2014-06/msg00003.html)) told me to add 2 lines to my texi file ([more info](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/Inserting-Quote-Characters.html)):

```
@codequoteundirected on
@codequotebacktick on
```

as well as add the latest version of [texinfo.tex](http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/texinfo/texinfo.tex) to my package.